# Android - Java HashMap keySet suddenly returns null

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-spinner

I have two methods:
The first one iterates over a `HashMap<String, String>` ("mWidgetStartConfig") to set the values of spinner widgets in a fragment. This method is always called in `onResume`.

The second method implements the `onItemSelected`callback method of the `OnItemSelectedListener` and updates the values in another `HashMap<String, String>` ("mWidgetCurrentConfig") according to which spinner item was selected.

Here are the methods:

```
protected void configureWidgets() {
    for(String tag : mWidgetStartConfig.keySet()) {
        int valueIndex = mSpinnerValues.indexOf(mWidgetStartConfig.get(tag));
        ((Spinner) mLayout.findViewWithTag(tag)).setSelection(valueIndex);
    }
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long id) {
    String tag = (String) v.getTag();
    String value = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    mWidgetCurrentConfig.put(tag, value);
}
```

The weird thing is, that the first method works fine as long as I don't do anything in the second method (i.e. comment out the body). As soon as I do something in the second method, I get a `NullPointerException` in the first method when it is called the **second** time, with the `String` "tag" being null (the first call works fine somehow).

I really don't get why this happens, since I don't access or change the "mWidgetStartConfig" variable at all in the second method. I've also tried different ways to iterate over the `HashMap` - same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So the reason was, that i called `v.getTag()` instead of `parent.getTag()` which somehow had an influence on the first method, too.